# On a particular $K[x,y]$-module

Tags: ring-theory, homological-algebra, injective-module, flatness

This is a follow up from [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627860/projective-module-polynomial-ring/627877#comment1323551_627877).

Suppose  $K$ is a field and consider $K$ as a $K[x,y]-$module where the scalar product is defined by  $f(x,y)\cdot k = f(0,0)\cdot k$.

> Is $K$ injective or flat as $k[x,y]-$module?

**COMMENT:** It is proved by @GeorgesElencwajg that $K$ is not projective.

Comment: Hint: $K=K[x,y]/(x,y)$, and $R/I$ is almost never flat over $R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Non injectivity**
An injective module $M$ over  a domain $D$ is divisible: this means that for every non-zero $d\in D$ and every $m\in M$ there exists $n\in N$ with $m=d\cdot n$.
But here, choosing $m=1\in K=M$, it is impossible to write $1=x\cdot n\in K$ since for every $n\in K$ one actually has $x\cdot n=0$
So $K$ is not injective.

**Non flatness**
1)  The $K[x,y]$-module $K$ is of finite presentation.  Hence it is flat if and only if it is projective.
Since I already proved that $K$ is not projective, it is not flat either.

2) Here is another proof, in the vein of  Martin's comment.
 If $I\subset R$ is an ideal in a ring, for the quotient $R/I$
 to be  flat over $R$ [it is necessary that $I=I^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/487240/3217).
Since $(x,y)\neq(x,y)^2$, $K=K[x,y]/(x,y)$ is not flat over $K[x,y]$.

3) A third proof is obtained by remembering that a flat module over a domain is torsion-free.
Since $x\cdot 1=0\in K$ even though $x\neq 0\in K[x,y]$ and  $1\neq 0\in K$, the module $K$ has torsion and is thus not flat.

**Edit**
As a generalization of the above, it might be worth remembering that if $0\subsetneq I\subsetneq R$ is a non-trivial ideal of a domain, the $R$-module $R/I$ is never projective, nor injective, nor flat.

Comment: Dear @rschwieb, you are perfectly right of course: I have corrected my blunder. Thank you very much for your attentive reading [and I found your "n injective" quite amusing ...] .

Comment: Dear Georges : No problem :) I always enjoy your answers...